# Why an extra layer of indirection when calling functions?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly, linker, visual-studio-2017

**Background:**

So I've been watching some tutorial videos on how the compiler and linker (in VS 2017 VC++ compiler/linker) work by looking at assembly files to piece together everything. When I compile and link these two cpp files together:

main.cpp *(note: I've removed implicit linking with c library and defined my own 'mainCRTStartup' funcion to making looking at result .exe file easier.)*

```
int Func1(int x);

int mainCRTStartup(void)
{
    Func1(3);

    return 0;
}
```

func1.cpp

```
int Func1(int x)
{
    x +=2;

    return x;
}
```

I get my resulting main.exe which looks something like this in assembly:

```
File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

  0000000140001000: CC                 int         3
  0000000140001001: CC                 int         3
  0000000140001002: CC                 int         3
  0000000140001003: CC                 int         3
  0000000140001004: CC                 int         3
@ILT+0(?Func1@@YAHH@Z):
  0000000140001005: E9 36 00 00 00     jmp         ?Func1@@YAHH@Z
@ILT+5(?mainCRTStartup@@YAHXZ):
  000000014000100A: E9 11 00 00 00     jmp         ?mainCRTStartup@@YAHXZ
  000000014000100F: CC                 int         3
  0000000140001010: CC                 int         3
  0000000140001011: CC                 int         3
  0000000140001012: CC                 int         3
  0000000140001013: CC                 int         3
  0000000140001014: CC                 int         3
  0000000140001015: CC                 int         3
  0000000140001016: CC                 int         3
  0000000140001017: CC                 int         3
  0000000140001018: CC                 int         3
  0000000140001019: CC                 int         3
  000000014000101A: CC                 int         3
  000000014000101B: CC                 int         3
  000000014000101C: CC                 int         3
  000000014000101D: CC                 int         3
  000000014000101E: CC                 int         3
  000000014000101F: CC                 int         3
?mainCRTStartup@@YAHXZ:
  0000000140001020: 48 83 EC 28        sub         rsp,28h
  0000000140001024: B9 03 00 00 00     mov         ecx,3
  0000000140001029: E8 D7 FF FF FF     call        @ILT+0(?Func1@@YAHH@Z)
  000000014000102E: 33 C0              xor         eax,eax
  0000000140001030: 48 83 C4 28        add         rsp,28h
  0000000140001034: C3                 ret
  0000000140001035: CC                 int         3
  0000000140001036: CC                 int         3
  0000000140001037: CC                 int         3
  0000000140001038: CC                 int         3
  0000000140001039: CC                 int         3
  000000014000103A: CC                 int         3
  000000014000103B: CC                 int         3
  000000014000103C: CC                 int         3
  000000014000103D: CC                 int         3
  000000014000103E: CC                 int         3
  000000014000103F: CC                 int         3
?Func1@@YAHH@Z:
  0000000140001040: 89 4C 24 08        mov         dword ptr [rsp+8],ecx
  0000000140001044: 8B 44 24 08        mov         eax,dword ptr [rsp+8]
  0000000140001048: 83 C0 02           add         eax,2
  000000014000104B: 89 44 24 08        mov         dword ptr [rsp+8],eax
  000000014000104F: 8B 44 24 08        mov         eax,dword ptr [rsp+8]
  0000000140001053: C3                 ret
  0000000140001054: CC                 int         3
  0000000140001055: CC                 int         3
  0000000140001056: CC                 int         3
  0000000140001057: CC                 int         3
```

**Issue:**

I have two issues that I'm struggling with here:

1.) In the video when the teacher inspects his .exe file after linking everything, he has the 'call' instruction followed by a hard coded address like 000040001000 but in my asm file I still have the symbol name `@ILT+0(?Func1@@YAHH@Z)` of the function I'm suppose to call. I thought the linkers job was to resolve this symbol and put in an absolute address for the .exe? I know this address my not be the final address when the exe is loaded into memory but still thought an absolute address like 000040001000 would have been put there.

2.) In the tutorial video when the 'call' instruction for Func1 is run inside VS debugger, the debugger jumps straight to the address which stores the beginning of the code for the function. However, for my exe (which you can see above) the call instruction first jumps to some other address first (represented by `@ILT+0(?Func1@@YAHH@Z)` in my asm file) AND THEN calls a jmp instruction which then jumps to the code for function Func1. Why is it I'm getting this double indirection in my code with the 'call' then 'jmp'?

Comment: 1) it is resolved, it's just a friendly service of your disassembler that it shows the symbol. Side note, it's relative address not absolute. 2) disable incremental linking that should get rid of ILT thunks.

Comment: That was it. Disables incremental linking with -opt:ref (easiest way I remember doing it) and everything worked! If you want to place this comment as the answer I can accept it

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio creates a jump table to most or all functions when doing a "debug" build, creating that "extra layer of indirection". If a "release" build is done, the jump table isn't created, and calls to functions have their addresses / offsets filled in by the linker.

Try doing a release build, perhaps a release build with the debug stuff turned on so that you can see function names. Note that turning on debug stuff for release builds requires changing project properties and source file(s) within the project properties.